# AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION:: startForegroundService() not allowed due to mAllowStartForeground

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Can't reproduce manually, got those stats from Crashlytics. Not sure how we can deal with this crash, do you have any idea why this crash may happen?

Actual result
There are several types of exception grouped by the Android OS, but the reason looks exactly the same

```
Fatal Exception: android.app.RemoteServiceException: Context.startForegroundService() did not then call Service.startForeground(): ServiceRecord{bc3065 u0 com.bandlab.bandlab/com.bandlab.media.player.notification.MediaPlaybackService}
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2269)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8653)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your app is starting a foreground service from the bacground and you are not calling startForeground() in your service onCreate() or onStartCommand on time. Your app has 5s period to call startForeground in your Service after you call Context.startForegroundService(). You can check if your service logic might have a bug causing startForeground to not be called in some scenarios. You can also add firebase logging to log the time of startForegroundService call and startForeground call, this will show in your crash report whether this is the actual problem.

This crash is quiet common and appears on various devices. It might be either a design problem in the android.

some references:

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes.html#back-all

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/76112072